# Formula for conditionally summing a range

Tags: google-sheets, sum, conditional-statements, formula

What I am trying to achieve is shown below. I am sure that there is a formula (or a few) that I can use to calculate it so I don't have to hardcode it for each column total. Perhaps it's a combination of `=SUM` and `=SUMIF` but I'm not sure how to build it with a #. Pseudocode of the solution to a single column is provided after the photo.

[image: Example]

```
FUNCTION getTotal (range)
  let total = 0
  FOR i = 0 TO range.total DO
    IF range[i].hasContents DO
      total += "# amount"
    ENDIF
  ENDFOR
  return total
ENDFUNCTION
```

PS: I am actually doing this on Google Spreadsheets so an excel only solution would **NOT** be helpful (i.e. don't give me a VBA script)

Comment: If you don't want to see any Excel related solutions, why use the Excel-formula tag? Excel and the inferior Google Spreadsheets are not the same. Removing the Excel-formula tag.

Comment: If you didn't want (and wouldn't accept) an Excel solution then it was foolish to include the `excel` technical tag on your question. While they share *some* traits and *some* functions/formula are interchangeable, a programming language is NOT one of them. In short, don't throw mud at a wall to see what sticks.

Comment: Apologies. I don't see why it was downvoted and changed. I accept the changes but don't see why the down vote is there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned SUMIF and I can't see what would not suit with:

```
=SUMIF(C1:C12,"X",$B1:$B12)
```

copied across, assuming `#` is in B1 and Column B is summed with `=SUM(B2:B12)`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Cheers!!